# Symfony 2 : Is it possible to import a PHP file in YAML file?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to pass a variable from PHP config file to a YAML file, I am not sure it will work or not as I cannot test it because of some token issues which is yet to be provided by client.

What I did is:

**In PHP file Config.php made an object of class Config:**

```
$obj = new Config();
$obj->processEnv();
$obj->define('PROD_PASSWORD', '12345');
```

**In YAML file:**

```
imports:
    - { resource: Config.php }

prod:
   doctrine:
   class: sfDoctrineDatabase
param:
   username: username
   password: %PROD_PASSWORD%
```

Please advise that is it a good practice to do or there are other ways I can achieve this?

Comment: What  at least is good practise to properly name that. The acronym is YAML and since september 2006 the recommended extension has been `.yaml`. The curly braces are superfluous. And you should take care that `%` is an indicator character that is not allowed by some parsers at the start of a token (don't know about symfony's), so you might want to quote `%PROD_PASSWORD%`, unless that is expanded before handing to the YAML parser

Comment: Yes, YAML requires quotes around `%PROD_PASSWORD%`, but I think the YAML parser in Symfony 2 still supports omitting them. Same goes for the file extension, nowadays Symfony uses `config.yaml` by default, but in Symfony 2 and 3 it was `.yml`

Comment: @Anthon thank you for the curly braces input, I dint notice them somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, mixing formats is perfectly fine and in some cases Symfony even recommends different formats, for example when you write a bundle that will be distributed the Best Practices recommend using XML whereas by default in your application YAML is the recommended choice. There is no performance drawback when using one format over the other (in production) as the configuration will be compiled and cached as a .php file in any case. As long as an appropriate loader is registered in the kernel it will be able to load the config and merge it with the rest.

As a best practice you should stick with one format to make it easier for others joining the project. Since all formats support the same features and performance is not affected by the format I don't see a reason to mix styles.